# WPF Binding error to class property, when other properties work fine

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I know there are a bunch of other similar SO posts like this, but none seem to have my scenario where I'm binding to a class property, AND other properties work just fine. I'm using MVVM pattern, **where my viewmodel is in c++/cli**. Since other properties work, it isn't my `DataContext` of my View. I have a `IsEnabled` on a `Button` binding to a bool in my ViewModel. Now, when try to bind to something like,

```
private:
bool thing = false;
public:
bool Thing
{
    bool get() { return thing; }
    void set(bool value) { thing = value; }
}
```

It works just fine. But then I do something like,

```
public ref class MyThingClass
{
    private:
    bool isEnabled = false;
    public:
    bool IsEnabled
    {
        bool get() { return thing; }
        void set(bool value) { thing = value; }
    };
};

public:
//Not sure if I need a handle (^) on this or not
MyThingClass MyThing;


//XAML
<Button x:Name="MyButton" IsEnabled="{Binding MyThing.IsEnabled}"/>
```

Something decides to break, the property doesn't bind, and in the output I get `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyThing ' property not found on 'object' ''MyViewModel' (HashCode=66641179)'. BindingExpression:Path=MyThing.IsEnabled; DataItem='MyViewModel' (HashCode=66641179); target element is 'Button' (Name='MyButton'); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')`

Please ask questions if I left anything out, or something doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
MyThingClass MyThing;
```

You create a *public field* named `MyThing`, not a *property*.

This needs to be defined as a property, not a field, in order to work with data binding:

```
property MyThingClass^ MyThing;
```

Also, if you want the property to update the UI, your `MyThingClass` will need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).  Also note the need for the handle type (`^`) since it's a managed class.

Comment: Ok, so apparently I'm going to need to change up my question. My ViewModel is actually in C++/CLI, so this method doesn't port over intuitively. I'm really sorry for switching things up, I figured things would port nicer, and C# was easier to write/read.

Comment: @SanjayCruze I'd close/accept this, and make a new question that shows the actual code (or at least code that's in C++/CLI)

Comment: Um, just changed it. Should I change it back, accept this answer, and ask a new question?

Comment: Thank you. Now how do I expose the `get` function? (And do I need a separate `MyThingClass`, one to be a property, one to be the variable?

Comment: Ended up making a local variable of `MyThingClass`, and adding a full `get` function onto `MyThing`. Is there a shorter way (since `IsEnabled` is a property)? And thank you very much, and I'm really sorry about the confusion.